# Two functions look the same to me, but one gives error on unsupported operand type(s) for 'function' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two functions that looks the same to me, but one returns error on `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'float'`. I do not understand why one function works with float, and the other does not.

I tried two things in addition to the code provided below. I tried to define `W_m` with `b_m` and `c_m` as variables, and calculate `J_m` inside `W_m` function. And I tried simply calling `J_m` and then using the result. Neither works.

All below with linespace is in separate code blocks in a big Jupyter Notebook script.

```
b_m=0.02 #m (50x20mm Cu bar)

c_m=0.05 #m (50x20mm Cu bar)

def J_m(c_m, b_m):
    J_m=((power(c_m,3))*b_m)/12.0
    return J_m

J_m(c_m, b_m)
```

This returns `2.08333....9e-07`

Then I try this:

```
def W_m(J_m, c_m):
    W_m=J_m/(c_m/2.0)
    return W_m

W_m(J_m, c_m)
```

and get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'float'`

why?

Comment: You probably want to pass `c_m`, not `J_m`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already defined `J_m` to be a function in the first part of the code. In your other function you try to define a variable with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! Solved all my problems!